# Запись строки в двумерный массив

Tags: c

Вкратце, мне нужно записать несколько строк в один массив, вот я и взял двумерный массив, т.к массив указателей не подойдет.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    int quantily,i;
    printf ("Введите количество слов: ");
    scanf("%d",&quantily);
    char str[quantily][100];
    for (i=0;i<quantily;i++)
    {
        printf ("Введите %d-ое слово: ",i+1);
        scanf("%s",(str+i));

    }

    return 0 ;
 }
```

`%s` на вход же требует адрес, так почему мне компилятор выводит предупреждение когда я пишу `(str+i)` , а когда пишу `*(str+i)` никаких предупреждений не вылетает. В чем дело?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потому что выражение `(str+i)` имеет тип `char (*)[100]`, т. е. *указатель на массив из 100 символов*. Вам в `scanf` нужно передать просто *массив из 100 символов*, т. к. имя массива [почти всегда приводится к указателю](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641957/is-an-array-name-a-pointer). Т. е. передавать вам нужно именно `*(str + i)` или лучше будет использовать синтаксический сахар C: `str[i]`.

`(str + i)` и `*(str + i)` — это один и тот же адрес, но два эти выражения имеют разный тип, а из-за несовпадения типа аргумента со спецификатором формата (`%s`) компилятор выводит предупреждение:

```
warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'char (*)[100]' [-Wformat]
        scanf("%s", (str + i));
```

Comment: Но при одномерном массиве мне же нужно передавать указатель

Comment: @собачка, смотрите. `str[i]` — это массив из 100 символов. Когда вы передадите его в функцию `scanf` в качестве аргумента он неявно преобразуется в указатель.

Comment: почему он преобразуется в указатель?

Comment: @собачка, таково правило языка: «*Except when it is the operand of the sizeof operator, or the unary & operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined*» — ISO Sec. 6.3.2.1.

Comment: То есть это нужно запомнить, а не понять?

Comment: @собачка, ну… да. Просто язык C так устроен. В другом языке программирования будут свои правила, которые тоже нужно будет запомнить. От этого никуда не денешься.

Comment: Ну хорошо, спасибо за ваш подробный ответ))

Comment: @собачка, был рад помочь)